# How to retry an InvokeHTTP processor specific number of time

Tags: apache-nifi

I am fetching JSON data from an API using the InvokeHTTP processor. The criteria are: if the data isn't fetched, it will retry 3 times and if it still fails, it will send a notification by email. I am new to NiFi, so how shall I implement this?

Comment: http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.13.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.RetryFlowFile/index.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a custom workflow to retry the specific number of times. After getting response from invoke HTTP you can set counter attribute having value as 0 and if you did not get response from API you can increase that attribute by one and send the flowfile back to input of invoke http. Every time you get the response of API you can check if this attribute reached the maximum retry value and if it did, you can terminate the data according to your requirement.

Comment: I didn't get it properly. Can you explain with images?

Answer (score 0):

If anybody still interested to know, the Version 1.16.0 & above has a feature of straightforward retry process.

> Framework Level Retry now supported.  For many years users build flows in various ways to make retries happen for a configured number of attempts.  Now this is easily and cleanly configured in the UI/API and simplifies the user experience and flow design considerably!  To those waiting for years for this thank you for your patience.

For eg. The following snapshot shows, the processor would attempt 3 retries after 2 mins of back off period.
[image]